# How to restrict a certain role from using a command (discord.py)

Tags: discord, discord.py

I've already seen the variant where you **allow a certain role to use a command**.
However, I'm trying to achieve the exact opposite: How to **disallow a certain role from using a command**.

I have searched around stack overflow and found no answer, nor did I found an answer on the official discord.py documentation.
Any sort of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Check inside command

```
@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx: commands.Context):
    blacklisted_role = ctx.guild.get_role(ID)

    if not any(role == blacklisted_role for role in ctx.author.roles):
        await ctx.send("world!")
```

##### Own Decorator

A more elegant way is to create your own decorator. It's more like the opposite of [`has_any_role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=has_any_role#discord.ext.commands.has_any_role).

```
from discord.ext import commands

def has_not_any_role(*roles):
    async def extended_check(ctx):
        return not any(role.id in roles for role in ctx.author.roles)

    return commands.check(extended_check)

@bot.command()
@has_not_any_role(492212595072434186)
async def hello(ctx: commands.Context):
    await ctx.send("world!")
```

If `extended_check` returns `True` the message will be sent. If it return `False` it throws a `discord.ext.commands.errors.CheckFailure` error which then can be catched in `on_command_error`.

---

###### References:

- [`Member.roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.roles)
- [`commands.check`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.check)

Answer (score 5):

`author.roles`  returns a list of `discord.Role` so just check if the role you specify is contained in that list, and if so, exit the command early.

**Using Role Id (Preferred)**

```py
@bot.command()
async def command_without_specific_role(ctx):
    if role_id in [role.id for role in ctx.author.roles]:
        return

    ...
```

**Using Role Name**

```py
@bot.command()
async def command_without_specific_role(ctx):
    if role_name in [role.name for role in ctx.author.roles]:
        return

    ...
```

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder the if statement isn't even correct. `ctx.author.roles` is a list of `discord.Role` so it will be always `False`.

Comment: @puncher what about `if "role_name" in [role.name.lower() for role in ctx.author.roles]`

Comment: yeah but it's still not a good practice. IDs are **unique**, role names aren't.

Comment: okay makes sense. i'll update the original answer using id. has been a while since i used d.py

Comment: It's still wrong. IDs are integers not strings. Also why should you do `role.name.lower()`? It makes it even more inaccurate.

Comment: @puncher, also, `Role.name`s are better, as even if the role is deleted and another is created with the same name (usually is for the same purpose), the code would work correctly. `Role.id`s are better, as even if the role's name is changed, the code would work. Both are equal. And I'd prefer `Role.name` because of what usually happens in Discord servers; however, if it's a big and formal server, you can probably use the other. I suggest you rollback to the original answer ('Revision 1'), and just change `ctx.author.roles` to `ctx.author.roles.name`. You can also click 'edit' beside Revision1.